# Laravel Livewire Pagination Result Disappear After Clicking Next Page/Page Number

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

i've been searching for a question like the one above but i can't find one, so i'm gonna make one

My problem is, when i make a very simple pagination with Laravel Livewire, the first page appear just fine, but when i click "Next Page/Page Number", the result just disappear, even though there are still more results to show, i'm absolutely got no idea, no mattter how i try.

[As you can see, the simple pagination work just fine, there is next and previous button and a very big next and previous picture below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JjMrj.png)

[But the moment i click next page or page number, the result just disappear, the total number of result even go to 0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Edczv.png)

Here is my Component code:

```
namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use DB;
use Livewire\WithPagination;

class Category extends Component
{   
    use WithPagination;
    public function render(Request $request)
    {   
        $id = $request->id;

        $product_count = DB::table('product')->where('category_id', $id)->count();

        $page = $request->page ?? 1;

        $product_all = DB::table('product')->where('category_id', $id)->paginate(3);

        return view('livewire.category',[
            'product_all' => $product_all,
            'product_count' => $product_count,
            'page' => $page,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Here is my view code:

```
<div class="row">
    @foreach ($product_all as $product)
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-12 mt-4 pt-2">
        @php
            product($product);
        @endphp
    </div>
    @endforeach   

    <!-- PAGINATION START -->
    @if ($product_all instanceof \Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator)
    {{ $product_all->links() }}
    @endif
    <!-- PAGINATION END -->
</div>
```

And a small notice, i try pagination(just normal laravel pagination) without livewire and it work perfectly fine, that's why i am really clueless of what is happening

I have already include the livewire @livewireStyles and @livewireScripts, and i can't find an answer anywhere else cause i don't see any question that match my problem, and i'm kinda new to livewire

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problems is related with the request parameter on the render method of the livewire component, once livewire on rerender can't access the request value, until next browser refresh.

```
public function render(Request $request)
```

instead, use livewire properties to bind the id and page with values livewire can read on rerenders

```
@livewire('some-component', ['category_id' => $parent_category_id, 'page' => $parent_page_value])
```

Like above, livewire bind this values to self properties and read from them on rerender

```
public $category_id, $page;

public function render()
{
   $product_count = DB::table('product')->where('category_id', $this->category_id)->count();
   $product_all = DB::table('product')->where('category_id', $this->category_id)->paginate(3);

   return view('livewire.category',[
      'product_all' => $product_all,
      'product_count' => $product_count,
      'page' => $this->page,
   ]);
}
```

Comment: thank you, you solve my 9 hours just looking at the monitor with no clue how to do, thanks a lots

Comment: good to know it. go ahead then and recover all that time! jjj